# Python - Taking a PEM file and using it to authenticate with a external HTTPS server

Tags: python, linux, ssl, pem

So I have looked around for a while to try to find a answer for this but has had little luck. My issue is I am trying to build a python script to connect to a web server that is running on HTTPS, however it uses only PEM files to authenticate. A lot of the examples I have found show using PEM files with a username and password.

The website I am referring to is a Verizon SSL certificate manager website. It's how my company (cant name) manages there external SSL certs. My idea is to build a script to connect to the website and then take a list of SSL certs that are expiring and parse through it and email the SSL tech contact and let them know its expiring.

The part I am getting stuck on is the connecting to the website using  only the PEM file. I was wondering what would be the best way of doing that ?

Comment: Can you just set up `/.ssh/config` to associate PEM files with known hosts?

Comment: Search on how to use client certificates with python httplib2 or requests library. It is simple and [documented](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/).

Comment: @Quentin Donnellan - not sure, have not tried that yet.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich - awesome info, thank you. That looks like it will get me pointed in the right direction.

Comment: Cool, hopefuly Steffen's info helps, if you are interested in the ssh config, take a look: https://gist.github.com/qdonnellan/915279fb98e1e5d757a7